# Magento: Product Catalog Images Not Upload

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, php-5.4, image-upload, upload

**Magento** ver. 1.9.2.0

**PHP** Ver. 5.6

[image]

Comment: Have log error in /var/log ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the /media directory and all subdirectories have your Apache's user's group (usually 'www-data' or 'httpd'):

```
sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/magento/media
```

Also check the permission is set right to

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/magento/media
```

Comment: _thanks_  **@userpk**
i already do this but it not work for me

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me.
https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader
open this link and follow the instructions please